# I am getting perfect result by doing illustrate on the result of join, but dump not working on the same

Tags: apache-pig, inner-join

I am using the below lines of code :

```
 student = load 'test/Pig/student' using PigStorage(' ') as (name:chararray,roll:int);

result = load 'test/Pig/results' using PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,status:chararray);

passroll = FILTER result by status == 'pass';

 store passroll into 'test/Pig/passroll';

pass = load 'test/Pig/passroll/part-m-00000' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,status:chararray);

 stupass = JOIN pass by id, student by roll;

studentname = FOREACH stupass GENERATE student::name;
```

illustrate `studentname` is giving perfect result of student names those who have pass.

but dump `studentname` is giving Encountered Warning `ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FI
ELD 19 time(s)`.

Comment: "illustrate" would only show results from a small subset of inputs.  Are you saying "dump" does not show any outputs?

Comment: why are you storing the `passroll` and reading back as `pass`.  following will achieve the same thing `JOIN passroll by id, student by roll;`